# Random background image for a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I am trying to find a way that I can have an image that takes up the whole browser window and is responsive. Every time the page is loaded I would like the background image to change from a select group of photos that I have locally.

I have tried a few solutions on here but nothing is really working. The HTML I have is:

```
<div id="container">

  <img src="Images/IMG_3764.JPG" alt="An island in the middle of the sea in Turkey" id="backgroundImage">

</div>
```

The CSS I have is:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

#backgroundImage {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

html, body { 
overflow: none !important; 
overflow-x: none !important; 
overflow-y: none !important; 
}
```

One of the JS solutions that I have tried is this:

```
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#backgroundImage').attr('src',image[x]);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of javascript code you have tried that did not work?

Comment: @Bastiaanus yeah sorry, just included it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to need to have an array of images stored in JavaScript like so:

```
var picArr = [imageSrc1 ,imageSrc2 ,imageSrc3];
```

After which you'll need some kind of random number that conforms to the amount of image src's you have in the above array.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

You'll be using `Math.random()` here

Then you'll need to create a function that shall be executed when the document loads that changes the src of your background above.

Your final function might look like this:

```
var picArr = ['src0', 'src1', 'src2', 'src3', 'src4', 'src5', 'src6', 'src7', 'src8', 'src9', ];

var myNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', picArr[myNumber]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, but this one worked straight away, just needed to add the images!

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you could do something like this

[See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ttnwupru/1/).

```js
    var images = ['http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg', 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg', 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c6/8a/51/c68a5157020c8555ca781839d754a1a0.jpg'];

    var randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

     $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#container").css("background-image", "url('" + images[randomImage] + "')");
    })
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I try this I don't get anything on the webpage at all

Comment: You'll need to use the correct ID in the `$("body").css("background-image", "url('" + images[randomImage] +"')");` so use `$("backgroundImage").css("background-image", "url('" + images[randomImage] +"')");`

Comment: you probably want to use `$('#container')`

Comment: I'm fairly certain you could achieve this using Sass without any Javascript, Is that something OP would be interested in?